# GStreamer H264 video and KLV mpegtsmux error

Tags: gstreamer, h.264

I need your help! I have a .ts video file that carries H264 video and KLV metadata stream. I need to demux the video, overlay an image on video and create a new .ts file with it and the same KLV stream.
I’ve tried different approaches using GStreamer without success. The following pipeline is the simplest version I’ve tried:

gst-launch-1.0 -t -v --gst-debug=3 filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/videoTeste.ts ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! “video/x-h264” ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc bitrate = 10000 ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! queue ! mpegtsmux name=encod encod. ! filesink location=/home/ubuntu/teste.ts async=false demux. ! “meta/x-klv” ! queue ! encod.

This is the output:A definir pipeline para PAUSA …
0:00:00.053580180 19705 0x5647f4e61c00 WARN basesrc gstbasesrc.c:3600:gst_base_src_start_complete: pad not activated yet
Pipeline é PREROLLED …
A definir pipeline para REPRODUZIR …
New clock: GstSystemClock
/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter3: caps = meta/x-klv
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter4: caps = meta/x-klv
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter4.GstPad:src: caps = meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:sink: caps = meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstQueue:queue1.GstPad:src: caps = meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/MpegTsMux:encod.GstPad:sink_66: caps = meta/x-klv, parsed=(boolean)true

(gst-launch-1.0:19705): GStreamer-CRITICAL **: 11:56:27.551: gst_segment_to_running_time: assertion ‘segment->format == format’ failed
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)byte-stream, alignment=(string)nal
0:00:00.054452886 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 15508 will be dropped
0:00:00.054506922 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 24322 will be dropped
0:00:00.054553198 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 21270 will be dropped
0:00:00.054591203 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 26579 will be dropped
0:00:00.054630071 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25436 will be dropped
0:00:00.054663925 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25557 will be dropped
0:00:00.054697735 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25598 will be dropped
0:00:00.054734388 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25866 will be dropped
0:00:00.054768227 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25782 will be dropped
0:00:00.054805325 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 26169 will be dropped
0:00:00.054838313 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25996 will be dropped
0:00:00.054875026 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25735 will be dropped
0:00:00.054908194 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25991 will be dropped
0:00:00.054940617 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 26233 will be dropped
0:00:00.054974736 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19915 will be dropped
0:00:00.055007396 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 26268 will be dropped
0:00:00.055037714 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19609 will be dropped
0:00:00.055069936 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 26015 will be dropped
0:00:00.055103250 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19613 will be dropped
0:00:00.055135263 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25920 will be dropped
0:00:00.055164929 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19735 will be dropped
0:00:00.055197066 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25851 will be dropped
0:00:00.055235518 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19638 will be dropped
0:00:00.055268897 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 19733 will be dropped
0:00:00.055301416 19705 0x5647f4dfcea0 WARN h264parse gsth264parse.c:1349:gst_h264_parse_handle_frame: broken/invalid nal Type: 1 Slice, Size: 25492 will be dropped

Seems to be a sync problem between the H264 frames and the KLV chunks, I think…
I’ve tried changing the place of the queues, using a “tee” after filesrc and using separated demux, multiqueue…
I’m able to create a .ts file with H264 video only and I’m also able to extract and save to a file the KLV data. I’m even able to do this in the same pipeline:

gst-launch-1.0 -t -v --gst-debug=0 filesrc location=/home/ubuntu/videoTeste.ts ! tee name=t t. ! queue ! tsdemux name=demux demux. ! h264parse ! “video/x-h264” ! avdec_h264 ! x264enc bitrate = 10000 ! video/x-h264, profile=baseline ! mpegtsmux name=encod encod. ! filesink location=/home/ubuntu/teste.ts async=false t. ! queue ! tsdemux ! “meta/x-klv” ! filesink location=/home/ubuntu/klv.dat async=false

Do you have any suggestions to solve this?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you make the test data available?